# Google Desktop index path

Tags: google, google-desktop

Google Desktop save index file in home folder. Index file is too large for home folder, so i need to move the file and also set new path for index file.
How could i do this in google desktop? There is a way in window but i did not find any post for linux. Is it really possible to define google desktop index file path ?

Comment: Where is it actually located? In a specific directory? If yes, then you could use a symlink.

Comment: default dir is: ~/.google/desktop/repo. I am afraid, will it work with symbolic link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rename the directory `repo` in `~/.google/desktop/` to something else.
2. Create a directory in the destination location.
3. Move everything from the renamed directory into the destination directory.
4. Create a symlink to the destination directory, call it `repo`. (In nautilus, right click on the destination directory and click "Make Link")

EDIT: I think you meant that `repo` is a file. Then instead of making the new directory, just copy the file to the new destination and make a symlink to it.

Comment: after changing : google desktop return error 'zero size reply'. I check permission and owner of repo(another dir). drwxrwxrwx 3 developer root 4096 2011-09-17 03:46 repo

Comment: @shantanu Wait, is `repo` a file? If yes, then you need to move the directory `desktop` and create a symlink to it.

Comment: repo is a directory. i have created symbolic link which cause google desktop error

Comment: Hmm... Try doing it with the whole desktop directory...